# How to translate field values in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, translation, odoo-10

We can see all the translated items using **Settings > Application Terms > Translated Terms**.

But there is no dynamic translated values in the list. All are static values like labels. However, I made some queries in PostgreSQL and I found some translated values there.

Is there any UI **to check and edit the translated field values in Odoo 10?**

Answer (score 2):

Usually the field itself has a little globe on the right upper corner in edit mode. For example in products:

[image]

Click to open the field's translations:

[image]

Another, and in my opinion better, way is using the module [web_translate_dialog](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/b8e1337079b4d240dce1651cf4322dfebb349233/web_translate_dialog) from OCA.

And that's it. You already found the menu with the list of records from model `ir.translation` which show every translation for the system. The little globe is opening it, too, but filters the correct field.

Comment: :Thanks for the additional information about translations